# Decorate "Contents" and "listof" pages with TiKZ in scrbook class

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles, chapters, scrbook

I'm using the `scrbook` class to write a document because of its high flexibility. The problem is when I tried to customize my chapters I succeeded in changing only the `mainmatter` chapters, but for `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures`, and `\listoftables` I couldn't do the same. What I need to add is a simple rule under the titles of these items as in following picture:

[image]

Most answers I have found rely on the `titlesec` package, which is not fully compatible with `KOMA script` and it will affect all chapters that are already well customized. I like using `TiKZ` for its power and high quality. Currently, I used `\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}` for customizing my chapters. Any idea how to do this for the `\frontmatter` pages? Thank you.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,
               twoside=false,%
               toc=listof,%
               toc=bibliography,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               captions=tableheading,%
               numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz,calc}  
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\raggedleft\linespread{1}}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrpage2}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\normalfont%
              {\fontsize{20}{30}\scshape\chapappifchapterprefix{}}
              {\fontsize{80}{30}\selectfont\thechapter}%
              \tikz{\coordinate(h);
              \draw[overlay,remember picture,line width=1.5pt]%
              ([yshift=-07pt]h)--++(-150mm,0)%
}}%

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\setstretch{1.62}
\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter{Dedication}        %====== Dedication
\chapter{Acknowledgments}   %====== Acknowledgments
\chapter{Abstract}          %====== Abstract
\tableofcontents            %====== Table of Contents
\listoffigures              %====== List of Figures
\listoftables               %====== List of Tables
\chapter{Abbreviations}     %====== List of Abbreviations
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter1}  
\chapter{Chapter2}  
\chapter{Chapter3}      
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix A}    
\backmatter
\chapter{References}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load `etoolbox` and change `\chapterheadendvskip` to insert the line in chapter titles outside of mainmatter:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto{\chapterheadendvskip}{%
  \if@mainmatter\else% only outside mainmatter
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}\hfill%
    \tikz{\coordinate(h);%
      \draw[overlay,remember picture,line width=1.5pt]%
        ([yshift=-7pt]h)--++(-150mm,0);}%
    \par\fi%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code:

Note, that the package `scrpage2` is outdated. The successor is `scrlayer-scrpage`.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,
               twoside=false,%
               toc=listof,%
               toc=bibliography,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               captions=tableheading,%
               numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\linespread{1}}
\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\raggedleft}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{onpsinit=\linespread{1}}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\normalfont%
              {\fontsize{20}{30}\scshape\chapappifchapterprefix{}}
              {\fontsize{80}{30}\selectfont\thechapter}%
              \tikz{\coordinate(h);
              \draw[overlay,line width=1.5pt]%
              ([yshift=-7pt]h)--++(-150mm,0);%
}}%

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto{\chapterheadendvskip}{%
  \if@mainmatter\else% only outside mainmatter
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}\hfill%
    \tikz{\coordinate(h);%
      \draw[overlay,remember picture,line width=1.5pt]%
        ([yshift=-7pt]h)--++(-150mm,0);}%
    \par\fi%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
%\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\setstretch{1.62}
\chapter{Dedication}        %====== Dedication
\textbf{\KOMAScriptVersion}

\blindtext
\chapter{Acknowledgments}   %====== Acknowledgments
\blindtext
\chapter{Abstract}          %====== Abstract
\blindtext
\tableofcontents            %====== Table of Contents
%\listoffigures              %====== List of Figures
%\listoftables               %====== List of Tables
%\chapter{Abbreviations}     %====== List of Abbreviations
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\blinddocument
\appendix
\blinddocument
\backmatter
\chapter{References}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

---

You can also left-justify the chapters outside mainmatter as asked in a comment. Use

```
\makeatother
\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\if@mainmatter\raggedleft\else\fi}
\makeatother
```

or

```
\makeatother
\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\if@mainmatter\raggedleft\else\raggedright\fi}
\makeatother
```

But then rule under this chapter titles should also be left aligned:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto{\chapterheadendvskip}{%
  \if@mainmatter\else% only outside mainmatter
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}\noindent%
    \tikz{\coordinate(h);%
      \draw[overlay,remember picture,line width=1.5pt]%
        ([yshift=-7pt]h)--++(150mm,0);}%
    \par\fi%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,
               twoside=false,%
               toc=listof,%
               toc=bibliography,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               captions=tableheading,%
               numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\linespread{1}}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{onpsinit=\linespread{1}}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\normalfont%
              {\fontsize{20}{30}\scshape\chapappifchapterprefix{}}
              {\fontsize{80}{30}\selectfont\thechapter}%
              \tikz{\coordinate(h);
              \draw[overlay,line width=1.5pt]%
              ([yshift=-7pt]h)--++(-150mm,0);%
}}%

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto{\chapterheadendvskip}{%
  \if@mainmatter\else% only outside mainmatter
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}\noindent%
    \tikz{\coordinate(h);%
      \draw[overlay,remember picture,line width=1.5pt]%
        ([yshift=-7pt]h)--++(150mm,0);}%
    \par\fi%
}
\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\if@mainmatter\raggedleft\else\fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
%\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\setstretch{1.62}
\chapter{Dedication}        %====== Dedication
\textbf{\KOMAScriptVersion}

\blindtext
\chapter{Acknowledgments}   %====== Acknowledgments
\blindtext
\chapter{Abstract}          %====== Abstract
\blindtext
\tableofcontents            %====== Table of Contents
%\listoffigures              %====== List of Figures
%\listoftables               %====== List of Tables
%\chapter{Abbreviations}     %====== List of Abbreviations
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\blinddocument
\appendix
\blinddocument
\backmatter
\chapter{References}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) Thank you @esdd, it works perfect.  Can I also left-justify the titles without affecting the main chapters?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. See my extended answer